# replace javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá, estou querendo esconder um texto que contem "(numeros)", conseguir um método, porem so funciona no primeiro elemento, os outros continuam mostrando, como fazer um loop para todos os elementos ? 
segue meu código

```
 <div id="mydiv">
 <a  href="#" id="demo"> Mr Blue has a blue house, (0123dddddd4) and/ a blue car </a>   
 </div>


 <div id="mydiv">
  <a  href="#" id="demo1"> Mr Blue has a blue house, (0123dddddd4) and/ a blue car </a> 
 </div>




 <script>
 function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace( /\(.*\)/, '' );
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
 }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `.getElementById()` retorna só um elemento, o primeiro que encontrar. Tens de usar outro método como o `.querySelectorAll()` e um ciclo para iterar todos os elementos que queres.

Nota que `id` têm de ser únicas, não podes repetir elementos com o mesmo `id`. Sugiro mudares para `class` ou usar a estrutura do DOM para o teu seletor.

Uma versão do que queres fazer seria por exemplo:

```
function limpar(el) {
    var str = el.innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/\(.*\)/, '');
    el.innerHTML = res;
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv a');
[].forEach.call(links, limpar);
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3m3pc7bp/

Nesta suggestão uso o `.forEach()` importado dos métodos de Array, podes fazer com um ciclo for assim:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    limpar(links[i]);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3m3pc7bp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer fazer esse tratamento para todos elementos `a`, você pode utilizar o `getElementsByTagName()`

Exemplo:

```
function myFunction() {
    var as = document.document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i=0; i < as.length; i++) {
         as[i].innerHTML = as[i].innerHTML.replace( /\(.*\)/, '' );
    }
}
```